# How to sum non-empty successive rows in deeply nested tibbles in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, tidyr

I have a huge tibble containing data from several experimental tasks, each of them having a lot of subjects, and each subject having their own dataframe of results (for the detail, it is an eye tracking experiment). I'm working on this structure in nested tibbles to have a clean reproducible environment instead of countless objects.

For each subject, I'd like to sum up the lines that follow each other and contain a value (in the experimental context, this means grouping together the frames from a single area that the subject has looked at). Here is an example of the structure of the data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  task_name = c("task_1", "task_2"),
  task_data = list(
    tibble(
        subject = c("S1", "S2"),
        data = list(
          tibble(
            var_1 = c(NA, 20, 12, NA, NA, NA),
            var_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 51, 10),
          ),
          tibble(
            var_1 = c(NA, NA, 15, 54, NA, NA),
            var_2 = c(NA, 13, NA, NA, NA, 10),
          )
        )
      ),
    tibble(
        subject = c("S1", "S2"),
        data = list(
          tibble(
            var_3 = c(3,  NA, NA, 10,  5, NA),
            var_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
          ),
          tibble(
            var_3 = c(3,  NA, NA, NA,  7, NA),
            var_4 = c(NA, NA, 20, 30, NA, NA)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

I want to sum the numbers in `var_1`/2/3/4, but only if they are successive, e.g. summing 20 and 12 in `var_1` and 51 and 10 in `var_2` for subject 1. Each row always has a value in a single column, so the column lengths are not an issue. The expected outcome for `S1` in `task_1` for instance is that `var_1` is `c(0, 32, 0, 0)` and `var_2` is `c(0, 0, 0, 61)`, therefore in a shorter tibble of 4 rows.

What I've tried, based on the ideas of several posts similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627972/summing-consecutive-values-broken-up-by-specific-value-in-r), is to create lagged columns to check the values before and after each row, sum them under specific conditions, then delete the helper lagged columns created in this process, and finally keep only one of the duplicate summed rows created.

It looks like this:

```r
df_summed <- 
  df |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    task_data = case_when(
      # We work only on task_1 for now for testing purposes
      task_name == "task_1" ~
        list(
          task_data |>
            rowwise() |>
            mutate(
              data = list(
                data |> 
                  mutate(
                    # Offsets the column to see what's behind
                    behind = lag(var_1), # <1>
                    # Replaces NAs with 0
                    behind = if_else(is.na(behind), 0, behind),
                    # Same with what's ahead
                    ahead  = lead(var_1),                       
                    ahead  = if_else(is.na(ahead), 0, ahead),  
                    # If the value is 0, keeps it, otherwise sums the lagged columns
                    summed = if_else(is.na(var_1), 0, var_1 + behind + ahead)
                  ) |> 
                  # Removes the columns that were created for the summing process
                  select(!c(var_1, behind, ahead)) |>
                  rename(var_1 = summed) |>
                  # Keeps only one of the two duplicate rows
                  unique()
                )
              )
          ),
      # Let's not touch task_2 right away, for convenience
      TRUE ~ list(task_data)
    )
  )
```

This `lag`/`lead` mechanism is verbose and I intended to make a pipe-friendly function from it to apply it to all the variables, but I can't even make it work in this reprex. What puzzles me the most is that *this code works perfectly if the variables are identical across tasks* (i.e. if I rename `task_3`/4 to `task_1`/2 here), but this is not the case in the real dataset. These variable names are the reason why I used `case_when` to isolate the tasks, but this does not cut it.

As mentioned above, the expected output of the code pasted here is to modify only `task_1`, have `var_1` equal to `c(0, 32, 0, 0, 0)` for `S1` and `var_1` equal to `c(0, 0, 69, 0, 0)` for `S2`, the lengths of `var_2` will also change in the process, but `task_2` should not be modified at all.

The following error is returned:

```r
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `task_data = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the right-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `data = list(...)`.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `behind = lag(var_1)`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! object 'var_1' not found
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::mutate(...)
 29. dplyr::lag(var_1)
```

I think I understand the error, but I can't figure out why `case_when` doesn't take care of isolating variables.

Do you see better ways to do this?  Also, do you have any ideas as to why the variable names make a difference and why `case_when` couldn't handle it?

*PS: this is my very first question on StackOverflow so I'm sorry if it's too verbose, I tried to make it as explicit and reproducible as possible since it's a very specific issue.*

Thank you !

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Neat reproducible data! I'm trying to understand the number of row on your expected output. I guess the problem is related to how to summarise it. What it would be the expected output if your input have two or more groups of consecutive data? Like this: `tibble(var_1 = c(NA, 20, 12, NA, 1, 1), var_2 = c(5, 5, NA, NA, 51, 10))`

Comment: Thank you! As I mentionned, each row can only have a value in a single column. It represents the time a subject has looked at a given spot, the spot being the `var_`, so your tibble wouldn't be possible. So I could only answer for an input like `tibble(var_1 = c(NA, NA, 20, 12, NA, NA, 1, 1), var_2 = c(5, 5, NA, NA, 51, 10, NA, NA))`, i.e. they looked a one spot - `var_1`, then the other, back and forth twice. The expected output would reflect that and be  `tibble(var_1 = c(0, 32, 0, 2), var_2 = c(10, 0, 61, 0))`.

Comment: Why do you have 4 rows instead of 5? You only summed 2 rows to reproduce 1 row. The rest of the rows never changed. ie you start with 6 rows but 2 of those became 1 so you end up with 5 row.

Comment: If we follow what my eventual code would do: (i) take `var_1`, transform NA to 0, sum 20+12 and 1+1, keep unique rows => `var_1` is `c(0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 2)`. By this point, `var_2` also changed due to `unique()`, it lost 2 rows. (ii) take `var_2`, which is now `c(5, 5, NA, 51, 10, NA)`, get NA to 0, sum 5+5, 51+10, `unique()`, then `var_2` becomes `c(10, 0, 61, 0)`. `var_1` is also reduced to 4 rows, hence the answer above. The reprex does not do this, but this is what it would be if I added a second part dedicated to `var_2` (which would be almost identical code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a user-defined function to make this pipe-friendly.

```
summed <- function(x){
  behind <-  lag(x,default = 0)
  ahead <- lead(x,default = 0)
  summed <- if_else(is.na(x),0,x+behind+ahead)
  summed
}



df_summed <- 
  df |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    task_data = case_when(
      # We work only on task_1 for now for testing purposes
      task_name == "task_1" ~
        list(
          task_data |>
            rowwise() |>
            mutate(
              data = list(
                data |> 
                  mutate(across(starts_with("var"),~summed(.x))
                  ) |> 
                  # Keeps only one of the two duplicate rows
                  unique()
              )
            )
        ),
      # Let's not touch task_2 right away, for convenience
      TRUE ~ list(task_data)
    )
  )

> (df_summed[[2]][[1]])[[2]][[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  var_1 var_2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0
2    32     0
3     0    61
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposition! We're getting closer, but this is still not functional on my end. First, the code had a problem with `var_4` of `S1` being only NAs, so adding `mutate(across(starts_with("var"),~as.numeric(.x)))` solved the issue. Then the code runs, and the result is very close, but some values seem to be deleted. On my end, the tibble you printed is tibble(var_1 = c(0, NA, 0, 0), var_2 = c(0, 0, NA, 61)) instead,,i.e. it seems 32 has been deleted. I'm trying things to fix that.

Comment: Oh wait, I got it! The problem came from NAs, and the line I wrote above was the wrong solution. Instead, doing `mutate(across(starts_with("var"),~if_else(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))` to replace NAs, then use your function `mutate(across(starts_with("var"),~summed(.x)))` works, I only needed to replace `if_else(is.na(x),0,x+behind+ahead)` in your function by `if_else(x == 0, 0, x + behind + ahead)`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Last thing: do you have any idea why my code wasn't working? I felt like my mutate was doing the same thing as your function, but apparently something was wrong with my syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. I use your data and this is what I get. Please let me know how to reproduce the issue and I will take a closer look.